# What is a tensor argument to Normal supposed to mean in Distributions Package of Pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, distribution, normal-distribution

I understand `torch.Normal(loc, scale)` is a class corresponding to univariate normal distribution in pytorch.
I understand how it works when loc and scale are numbers.
The problem is when the inputs to torch.Normal are tensors as opposed to numbers. In that case I do not understand it well. What is the exact interpretation/usage of such tensor arguments?
See for example y_dist in code below. loc and scale are tensors for y_dist. What does this exactly mean? I do not think this converts the univariate distribution to multivariate, does it? Does it instead form a group of univariate distributions?

```
import torch as pt
ptd = pt.distributions
x_dist = ptd.Normal(loc = 2, scale = 3)
x_samples = x_dist.sample()

batch_size = 256
y_dist = ptd.Normal(loc = 0.25 * pt.ones(batch_size, dtype=pt.float32), scale = pt.ones(batch_size, dtype=pt.float32))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, if `loc` (*a.k.a.* `mu`) and `scale` (*a.k.a.* `sigma`) are floats then it will sample from a [**normal distribution**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution), with `loc` as the *mean*, and `scale` as the *standard deviation*.

Providing tensors instead of *floats* will just make it sample from more than one normal distribution independently (unlike `torch.distributions.MultivariateNormal` of course)

If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/aeefe2ce31cac554d48de1372eb426dcf4a3a301/torch/distributions/normal.py#L45) you will see `loc` and scale are broadcasted to the same shape on `__init__`.

---

Here's an example to show this behavior:

```
>>> mu = torch.tensor([-10, 10], dtype=torch.float)
>>> sigma = torch.ones(2, 2)
>>> y_dist = Normal(loc=mu, scale=sigma)
```

Above `mu` is 1D, while `sigma` is 2D, yet:

```
>>> y_dist.loc
tensor([[-10.,  10.],
        [-10.,  10.]])
```

So it will get two samples from `N(-10, 1)` and two samples from `N(10, 1)`

```
>>> y_dist.sample()
tensor([[ -9.1686,  10.6062],
        [-10.0974,   8.5439]])
```

---

Similarly:

```
>>> mu = torch.zeros(2, 2)
>>> sigma = torch.tensor([0.001, 1000], dtype=torch.float)
>>> y_dist = Normal(loc=mu, scale=sigma)
```

Will *broadcast* `scale` to be:

```
>>> y_dist.scale
tensor([[1.0000e-03, 1.0000e+01],
        [1.0000e-03, 1.0000e+01]])

>>> y_dist.sample()
tensor([[-8.0329e-04,  1.4213e+01],
        [-1.4907e-03,  3.1190e+02]])
```